# Sum of four events

Tags: probability

Can someone help me solve the following problem on my probability course:

When leaving teacher's office student slams door shut. There's a name plate DARWIN on the door. Probability of single letter falling off is 1/11, and the events of falling are independent. Calculate the probability of following the case: First and last letter stay intact, and letters between them fall off, so that the name is split in two parts. So, for example, DAR_IN and D____N are favourable elementary events, but _AR__N and D_RW_N are not.

Comment: Considering the size of the problem, I would break into cases based on how many letters remain intact on the door and count those by hand.  How many ways can all 6 remain on the door and succesfully split into left-right parts with both first and final letter staying up?  Can 5 stay up and one fall with those properties?  4 up and two down with those properties, etc...

Comment: From there, note that each individual scenario where $k$ remain up and $6-k$ fell occurs with probability $\dfrac{10^k}{11^6}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @JMoravitz in the comments for the idea.

First off, if $D$ and $N$ have to stay up, we have $4$ possible letters that can fall off: $A,R,W$ and $I$. Now we break up our calculations into cases:

- $1$ letter falls off. We have that $R,W,I$ and $A$ are the possible letters that can fall and meet the desired criteria. Each of these has a probability 
  $\left(\frac{10}{11}\right)^5 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{11}\right)$ of occurring and since we have four of these cases then
  $$P(\{1 \text{ letter falls off} \})=4\cdot\left[\left(\frac{10}{11}\right)^5 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{11}\right)\right] =\frac{400000}{1771561}$$
- $2$ letters fall off. We have that $AR,RW$ and $WI$ are the possible combinations of $2$ letters that can fall off and still meet the criteria. (Can you see why we don't consider $AW,AI$ and $RI$?). Each of these combinations has  probability $\left(\frac{10}{11}\right)^4\cdot \left(\frac{1}{11} \right)^2$ of occurring, hence

$$P(\{2 \text{ letters fall off} \})=3\cdot\left[\left(\frac{10}{11}\right)^4 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{11}\right)^2\right] =\frac{30000}{1771561}$$

- $3$ letters fall off. By the same argument as before, $ARW$ and $RWI$ are the possible combinations of letters falling that we will consider. Each of these has  probability $\left(\frac{10}{11}\right)^3\cdot \left(\frac{1}{11} \right)^3$ and then
  $$P(\{3 \text{ letters fall off} \})=2\cdot\left[\left(\frac{10}{11}\right)^3 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{11}\right)^3\right]=\frac{2000}{1771561}$$
- $4$ letters fall off.  Since $D$ and $N$ have to stay up, the only possible case is that $ARWI$ falls off. Thus we have that
  $$P(\{4 \text{ letters fall off} \})=\left(\frac{10}{11}\right)^2 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{11}\right)^4=\frac{100}{1771561}$$

The only thing left to do is to sum all these cases up. 
So we define the event

$$A = \{\text{ letters fall off in such a way that they meet the criteria}\}$$
and then

$$P(A) =\frac{400000}{1771561}+ \frac{30000}{1771561}+\frac{2000}{1771561}+\frac{100}{1771561} = \frac{432100}{1771561}\approx 24.4 \%.$$

Comment: I wouldn't have thought about breaking the problem into four cases. Thank you very much for the exemplary and thorough answer!